# Changing font size in Java

Tags: java, fonts, size

I got my own custom font working in Java, but I have one problem, the font size seems to be staying at 1. I tried `font.deriveFont(20.0f);` at my initialize method, but, it didn't resize.

```
try {
    font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("D:/StanJump/mailrays.ttf"));
    font.deriveFont(20.0f);
} catch (Exception ex) {}
```

This is my code to create the font and try to change the size, but this didn't work. Any help on making it work, please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`deriveFont` returns a reference to a new font instance. Thus you need to assign it back to font, e.g.

```
font = font.deriveFont(20.0f);
```