# How to increase font size

Tags: java, fonts, awt, font-size

I have a little problem which seems silly to me but I cant find a solution to it on the internet. I have a code in which a font is initialized using a ttf file as follows.

```
  InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
            "dundalkh.ttf"));
  Font f = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
```

Now I use the Graphics Component to draw a String on the screen. Before drawing the string I use the following line:

```
 g.setFont(f);
 g.drawString("Title",300,30);
```

However the size of my font is very small. When I used the f.getSize() method it prints 1.
How should I increase the font size?

Comment: Can't you simply do something like `f.size = (10)` or something similar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing font size in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101886/changing-font-size-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pull a second Font object from the inital one using the deriveFont method:

```
Font f = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
Font newFont = f.deriveFont(10f);
```

Here is the doc entry for it:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont(float)

Comment: you're passing int instead of float and calling absolutely different method.

Comment: Good catch, case of sloppy answering, will fix.

Comment: @DenisTulskiy glad I caught you're comment!

Answer (score 2):

Font class has several `deriveFont` methods to create fonts with different parameters, particularly [font.deriveFont(12f)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont%28float%29) will create a font with size 12.

EDIT: make sure to use a float number for size, because there is deriveFont(int style) which sets font style, not size.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Font font = new Font(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, Font.BOLD, 30);
txt.setFont(font);
```